# How to Make an Autorun VCD with .exe files that automatically run videos in VCD palyers

Tags: video, autorun, vcd

I have an entertainment software that contains some videos to play
I separated videos into a folder
I want to make CD which can automatically run software on pc and also automatically run it's videos in VCD players
Please help me

Comment: VCD as in Video CD? Those things still exist? It's a standard format so just follow the specifications?

Comment: yes, What is the specifications ? i read somewhere that for vcd players you should define cd as playable type such when i write data cd, vcd player doesn't automatically play it's video

Answer (score 1):

There is a certain folder structure for VCDs and DVDs. This enables the player to look specific locations for specific files (subs in a folder, videos in another etc.) . You can achieve what you want by (assuming you know what autorun is and how to edit disk images):

1. Burning your media in VCD format
2. Making an image of disk
3. Editing the image by adding a proper autorun file and executable you want to run
4. Burning the edited image.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on VCDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_CD) has further information and also includes bits about the structure which would imply that's not just having folders on the disk to comply with the format. Otherwise a good answer.